# trying to find and remove nan values from path

Tags: python

Im trying to move some folders,the folder names i want to move are stored in a dictinary,but the problem is some folders dont exist in the orignal folder and those values have been copied as nan,
when i run this code,since there are nan values in the path it throws an error,

I have tried removing nan values by doing

`for i in some_list:
    if i == nan:
        do something(remove it)`

but it does not work

```
for level1,value1 in data_dict.items():
    for level2, value2 in value1.items():
        if value2 == nan:
            pass
        else:
            from_path = os.path.join(src_path,level1,value2)
            to_path = os.path.join(dst_path,level1,value2)
            print (from_path)
            os.mkdir(to_path)
        shutil.copytree(from_path,to_path)
```

so how can i remove nan values or ignore them in this case,
Any suggestions are helpful,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.isnan` or `math.isnan` to check `nan`.

`Numpy.nan` is not equal to any value, including `nan` itself.

```
for i in some_list:
    if numpy.isnan(i):
        pass
```

Thanks to @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for pointing out that `is` isn't proper for checking `nan` value.

Comment: No, the most idiomatic way of testing `nan` is `import math; math.isnan(x)` or `np.isnan` if you're using that.

Comment: Works brillianlty

Comment: @Ryan You cannot rely on `is` for obvious reasons.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Actually, it's not the most idiomatic way, but it works well. You don't downvote just because it's not the best solution!

Comment: @WrayZheng Thanks for the answer works well for my case